# How to add new empty column sequentially

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Data frame with these columns

```
dd = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'1':[1],'2':[1],'4':[1],'6':[1],'b':[1]})

   a  1  2  4  6  b
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

I want to add the missing column numbers like col 3 and col 5 is missing in its sequential manner, I can surely do this which gives the expected output.

```
dd['3'] = 0
dd['5'] = 0
dd=dd.reindex(columns= ['a', '1','2','3','4','5','6','b'])

   a  1  2  3  4  5  6  b
0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
```

I have thousands of columns I can't do it manually is there a way we can add them via a loop or something

Comment: Does the dataframe always have the first column  as 'a' and last column as 'b'

Comment: not really but the number columns are always in the between and sequentially. there can other alphabetical columns at the start or the end of the number columns

Comment: So we can expect the number sequence of column names to start from the second column to penultimate column right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's `filter` the numeric columns then using `get_loc` obtain the location in the dataframe correspoding to the start and end location of the numeric columns, finally use `reindex` with `fill_value=0` to reindex accordingly:

```
c = dd.filter(regex=r'^\d+$').columns
l1, l2 = dd.columns.get_loc(c[0]), dd.columns.get_loc(c[-1])
idx = np.hstack([dd.columns[:l1], np.r_[c.astype(int).min():c.astype(int).max() + 1].astype(str), dd.columns[l2 + 1:]])
dd = dd.reindex(idx, axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
   a  1  2  3  4  5  6  b
0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
for i in range(1, int(df.columns[-2])):
    if str(i) not in df.columns:
        df.insert(i, str(i), 0)
```

Prints:

```
   a  1  2  3  4  5  6  b
0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
```

Assuming this as per the comments that the numbered column sequence starts from second column till the second last column. The code also works if you have only one numbered column between start and end columns.